# Get the document data based on Title/document name

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

We have uploaded pdf file into Discovery service and using smart documentation we have marked the data as title and text/table..etc and spitted the pdf file into multiple pdf files based on title.

Now we want to get the data based on title/pdf filename and display the data.
Please let us know how we can get the pdf files and its data based on title.

Answer (score 0):

While building queries in *search for documents* use Discovery Query Language instead of natural language. In field select **extracted_metadata.title** or **extracted_metadata.filename** and choose the operator *contains* and provide the value. For more info follow the [Build Queries](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/discovery?topic=discovery-getting-started-with-querying#querying-step2)